# Do there exist imitation $BG$'s?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Let $G$ be a finite group. Let me call a connected finite CW-complex $X$ an imitation $BG$ relative to a prime $p$ if

1. $\pi_1(X) \cong G$
2. $\pi_k(X)$ is p-adically trivial for $k > 1$

Do there exist nontrivial imitation BG's?

Comment: @A.S.  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/79741/why-is-bg-infinite-dimensional-for-g-finite

Comment: @user1092847 Sorry, I thought of finitely-generated groups like Higman's group, not of finite groups.

Comment: What happens for the trivial group? Are there any finite simply connected CW-complexes with $pi_k$ p-adically trivial? Or can that not happen?

Comment: @ChrisSchommer-Pries I guess by taking covers you can probably find one with G trivial if there exists one for any G. But I don't know how to find such spaces